# kafka producer api 0.8.2.1 is not compatible with 1.0.1 broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i was using kafka producer which version is 0.8.2.1 to write to kafka broker which version is 1.0.1 async.
my code is like bellow:

```
KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(configs);
ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord("topic", "key", "value");
producer.send(producerRecord, new CallBack(){
@override
public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata,
                java.lang.Exception exception){
    if(metadata != null){
       System.out.println(metadata.partition() + "|" + metadata.offset());
}
});
```

i found that partition offset printed in my producer app's log at "onCompletion" method was bigger than kafka broker's offset which was query by shell command "./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell ".

my producer was set with the config "acks=all"

for example, partition 0's offset is 30000 in log, but is 10000 queryed by shell command.

is it caused by version compatible problem?

Answer (score 0):

The producer API was rewriten around Kafka 0.9 such that offsets are stored in Kafka, not Zookeeper. It's not clear if you've used GetOffsetShell with Zookeeper option or not.

Newer brokers are mostly backwards compatible down to version 0.10.2, but you shouldn't expect older clients less than those versions to work correctly with newer broker versions

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix